# Android button not responding and nothing showing in Logcat

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-button

I have a login activity and in it is nested a class that extends BroadcastReceiver to receive GCM registration token. I would like to store the registration token together with the user name and phone number after the user clicks the sign up button. So I instantiated the button in Oncreate method of the activity. So in the OnRecieve method of the BroadcastReciver I have this

```
signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {
                        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
                        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10);
                        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10);
                        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
                        //mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER);
                        //mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F);

                        //LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
                        //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (android.location.LocationListener) listener);
                        MyActivity maac = new MyActivity();
                        maac.startReceivingLocationUpdates();


                        Location mLastLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

                        if ((text != null && name.getText().length() > 0 && tele.getText().length() > 0) && (latitude > 0 && longitude > 0) && (isInputValid(name) && isInputValid(tele))){
                            namestring = name.getText().toString();
                            telestring = tele.getText().toString();
                            String la = String.valueOf(latitude);
                            String lo = String.valueOf(longitude);
                            SendLogin sendcreds = new SendLogin();
                            sendcreds.execute(text, namestring, telestring, la, lo);
                            //set number to 1 if user has already signed up if not set it to 0 so they sign up
                            sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("data", MODE_PRIVATE);
                            number = sharedPref.getInt("isLogged", 0);
                            if(number == 0) {
                                //Open the login activity and set this so that next it value is 1 then this condition will be false.
                                SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
                                prefEditor.putInt("isLogged", 1);
                                prefEditor.commit();
                            } else {
                                //Open this Home activity
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }

                        }else{
                            Log.i("login!!!", "caution: empty login");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "complete all boxes!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }

                    }catch (NullPointerException npo){
                        npo.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i("oops-----", "location is null in my opinion");
                    }
                }
            });
```

I have an asyncTask class that is also nested in the login activity, to send the credentials to a server in a separate thread. But when I click the button nothing happens and there is nothing in the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I forgot to start the service that my BroadcastReceiver was receiving from. So it has nothing to do with my button. Now that I have started my service I am getting a response but my location is null as is always with the last known location so I have to work around that :(